# Do two bijective sets have the same cardinality?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If there are two set $A$ and $B$ such that $A \rightarrowtail B$ (bijection), does $|A| = |B|$?

And if  $A \sim B$ (equinumerous), does $|A| = |B|$?

Comment: What's your definition of equinumerous? What's your definition of |A|? Are you only considering finite sets?

Comment: yes only finite set

Comment: Look here: $\;$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality

specifically,  "Definition 1"

Comment: Two sets are not bijective. Bijectivity is defined by functional relations between sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from definition of bijection. Every element of $A$ has a unique image in $B$ as it is injective well defined function and every element of $B$ is image of some element of $A$ as function is surjective. This forces $|A|=|B|$.